# how to show hidden div on ajax success call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am working on single page asp.net-mvc5 application....

I have a hidden div in my code, i tried to show this div on ajax success but failed...How can i achieve that, am i doing it right???

> Before putting "Display:None", animate function was working fine on
>   success, now its not working also due to hidden nature i guess...

**HTML**

```
<section class="block remove-top" id="contact-us" style="display: none;">
<form method="post" action="" name="contactform" id="contactform">
<div class="row">
<input name="FirstName" type="text" id="FirstName"/>
<input type="submit" class="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</section>
```

**Ajax**

```
<script>
    function packageSelect(PackageId) {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("SelectPackage", "Home")',
        dataType: "JSon",
        data: { "PackageId": PackageId },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            //$("#SecondInfo").focus({ scrollTop: "0px" });
            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#contact-us').offset().top }, 'slow');
        },
        error: console.log("it did not work"),
    });
};
</script>
```

Please if someone help, any kind of help will be appreciated....thanks for your time:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`show`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) the element before animation.

```
$('#contact-us').show();

$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#contact-us').offset().top }, 'slow');
```

If you want the element to be hidden:

```
$('#contact-us').show();

$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#contact-us').offset().top }, 'slow', function() {
    $('#contact-us').hide(); // Hide element after scroll is completed
});
```

Answer (score 6):

For

```
<section class="block remove-top" id="contact-us" style="display: none;">
```

you can show it using [**show()**](http://api.jquery.com/show/) like

```
$('#contact-us').show();
```

So, update your code to

```
function packageSelect(PackageId) {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("SelectPackage", "Home")',
        dataType: "JSon",
        data: { "PackageId": PackageId },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            //$("#SecondInfo").focus({ scrollTop: "0px" });
            $('#contact-us').show();
            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#contact-us').offset().top }, 'slow');
        },
        error: console.log("it did not work"),
    });
```

Comment: @SuhailMumtazAwan, you mean its still not working? Can you put up a fiddle using http://fiddle.net?

Comment: thanks for answer, although i can't accept it as i already did, +1 for effort

Answer (score 3):

Use `$('.element-name').show()` before animating.